# How to calculate the desired dead-time for 2 reversed pwm pulses?

Tags: embedded, stm32cubemx, stm32f103

I'm learning about stm32f103rct6 but I don't understand how to calculate the desired dead-time to configure on CubeMx as below. I don't know if it has a formula. If so, can you explain it to me? Thank you for taking the time to read
[image]

Comment: When you say reversed, do you mean logically inverted?